# Sidenotes with makeatletter/addtoreset begin with note 0, not 1

Tags: numbering, sidenotes

I'd like to restart the numbering of the sidenotes each subsection, to prevent sidenote 1000 at the end of the book. So I'm using this code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[maxfloats=100]{morefloats}

\setlength{\marginparwidth}{2cm}

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{sidenote}{subsection}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Hello}

\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}

\chapter{Hi}

\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}\blindtext\sidenote{hello}

\end{document}
```

The problem is however, that the sidenotes begin in each section (chapter) with sidenote 0, not sidenote 1. How can I solve this? Or is this a bug?

Comment: I get a 'too many unprocessed floats' error -- please make your file compilable

Comment: Sorry I've used pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode test.tex, I'll look into the reason of this problem

Comment: The morefloats package seems to solve the 'too many unprocessed floats' error, I'll update my example

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I don't see your answer anymore, but it was only a typo, a missing %. So your answer worked just as well. Thanks again!

Comment: I have deleted my answer after you complained and unaccepted it before giving me the chance to correct errors...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I'm sorry if I've offended you, but that was unintentional. I did unaccept it but only because at that time it didn't function the way I expected (without having any knowledge as to why - I do not no much about latex), and I want the answers to be up to date because others might learn from it also. After I learned the reason why it didn't work (typo), I wanted to accept it again, but it was gone already. I regret that, because it was a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll run into problems if a `\sidenote` doesn't appear *after* a `\subsection` command.

Anyway, there is a simple workaround. I use `openany` just to show that the counter is properly reset at chapter breaks (actually, it is only at subsections).

```
\documentclass[10pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage[maxfloats=100]{morefloats}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\geometry{
  marginparwidth=2cm,
}

\counterwithin*{sidenote}{subsection}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thesidenote}{\@arabic{\numexpr\value{sidenote}+1\relax}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Hello}

\section{Title}

\subsection{Subtitle}
Some text\sidenote{hello} that should occupy at least three lines, let's see whether 
this is enough, but probably not, so we add some words. But probably we need some
more of this boring text in order that it goes on and eventually split across three lines.
Some text\sidenote{hello} that should occupy at least three lines, let's see whether 
this is enough, but probably not, so we add some words. But probably we need some
more of this boring text in order that it goes on and eventually split across three lines.

\subsection{Subtitle}
Some text\sidenote{hello} that should occupy at least three lines, let's see whether 
this is enough, but probably not, so we add some words. But probably we need some
more of this boring text in order that it goes on and eventually split across three lines.
Some text\sidenote{hello} that should occupy at least three lines, let's see whether 
this is enough, but probably not, so we add some words. But probably we need some
more of this boring text in order that it goes on and eventually split across three lines.


\chapter{Hi}

\section{Title}

\subsection{Subtitle}
Some text\sidenote{hello} that should occupy at least three lines, let's see whether 
this is enough, but probably not, so we add some words. But probably we need some
more of this boring text in order that it goes on and eventually split across three lines.
Some text\sidenote{hello} that should occupy at least three lines, let's see whether 
this is enough, but probably not, so we add some words. But probably we need some
more of this boring text in order that it goes on and eventually split across three lines.

\subsection{Subtitle}
Some text\sidenote{hello} that should occupy at least three lines, let's see whether 
this is enough, but probably not, so we add some words. But probably we need some
more of this boring text in order that it goes on and eventually split across three lines.
Some text\sidenote{hello} that should occupy at least three lines, let's see whether 
this is enough, but probably not, so we add some words. But probably we need some
more of this boring text in order that it goes on and eventually split across three lines.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I've tested this as well, but your solution actually works better, because the text keeps looking good. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395127/sidenotes-make-text-look-ugly-footnotes-do-not-why