# Sidenotes make text look ugly, footnotes do not. Why?

Tags: footnotes, sidenotes

If I use the exact same text with the exact same note text, the sidenotes package makes the main text look ugly (ragging on both the left and right sides), while using the regular footnotes makes the text look just fine. Why is this? There shouldn't be a difference should there?

Example using sidenotes:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm,paperheight=230mm,bottom=20mm,top=30mm,inner=25mm,outer=35mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[maxfloats=100]{morefloats}

\setlength{\marginparwidth}{2cm}

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{sidenote}{subsection}

\RenewDocumentCommand \sidenote { o o +m }{%
  \addtocounter{sidenote}{1}%
  \sidenotemark[#1]
  \sidenotetext[#1][#2]{#3}
  \addtocounter{sidenote}{-1}%
  \@sidenotes@multimarker
}
\makeatother

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setcounter{sidenote}{0}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Hello}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim\sidenote{hello} veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure\sidenote{hello} dolor in reprehenderit\sidenote{hello} in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat\sidenote{hello} cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim\sidenote{hello} veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure\sidenote{hello} dolor in reprehenderit\sidenote{hello} in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat\sidenote{hello} cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim\sidenote{hello} veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure\sidenote{hello} dolor in reprehenderit\sidenote{hello} in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat\sidenote{hello} cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim\sidenote{hello} veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure\sidenote{hello} dolor in reprehenderit\sidenote{hello} in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat\sidenote{hello} cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim\sidenote{hello} veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure\sidenote{hello} dolor in reprehenderit\sidenote{hello} in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat\sidenote{hello} cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim\sidenote{hello} veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure\sidenote{hello} dolor in reprehenderit\sidenote{hello} in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat\sidenote{hello} cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 

\end{document}
```

[image: using sidenotes]

(As a side note (no pun intended), I also saw that the first sidenote does not vertically align with the 1 in the text, I do not not why.)

Example using footnotes (everything else the same):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm,paperheight=230mm,bottom=20mm,top=30mm,inner=25mm,outer=35mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage[para, perpage]{footmisc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Hello}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim\footnote{hello} veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure\footnote{hello} dolor in reprehenderit\footnote{hello} in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat\footnote{hello} cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim\footnote{hello} veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure\footnote{hello} dolor in reprehenderit\footnote{hello} in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat\footnote{hello} cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim\footnote{hello} veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure\footnote{hello} dolor in reprehenderit\footnote{hello} in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat\footnote{hello} cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim\footnote{hello} veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure\footnote{hello} dolor in reprehenderit\footnote{hello} in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat\footnote{hello} cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim\footnote{hello} veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure\footnote{hello} dolor in reprehenderit\footnote{hello} in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat\footnote{hello} cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim\footnote{hello} veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure\footnote{hello} dolor in reprehenderit\footnote{hello} in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat\footnote{hello} cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 

\end{document}
```

[image: using footnotes]

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: It has to do with https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395108/sidenotes-with-makeatletter-addtoreset-begin-with-note-0-not-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what the problem is, but if it's the margin of the main text, is because you are adding a lot of spaces...

```
\RenewDocumentCommand \sidenote { o o +m }{%
\addtocounter{sidenote}{1}%
\sidenotemark[#1]%
\sidenotetext[#1][#2]{#3}%
\addtocounter{sidenote}{-1}%
\@sidenotes@multimarker
}
```

(Notice the "%"). Spaces are ignored in LaTeX3 commands only if you use `\ExplSyntaxOn`/`Off` commands...

[image]

If, on the other hand, you are worried by the different length  of the marker when passing from 9 to 10, you can...

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter

\RenewDocumentCommand \sidenotetext { o o +m }
{
    \IfNoValueOrEmptyTF{#1}
    {
        \@sidenotes@placemarginal{#2}{\makebox[2em][l]{\textsuperscript{\thesidenote}}{}~#3}
        \refstepcounter{sidenote}
    }
    {\@sidenotes@placemarginal{#2}{\makebox[2em][l]{\textsuperscript{#1}}~#3}}
}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

[image]

(Notice, I left a bit more space for the marginnotes with

```
 \usepackage[paperwidth=170mm, paperheight=230mm,bottom=20mm,top=30mm,inner=25mm,outer=65mm]{geometry}
```

)

Comment: So if I understand this properly, the problem was the missing %?

Comment: Yes. Each "end of line" in your macro, after `\sidenotemark[#1]` etc, is generating a *new* space, because `LaTeX` thinks the spaces are separated by whatever the macros generate. The space *after* `\sidenote{...}` in your document is also generating a space, which is the only one you want to have.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by a solution to another problem, [Sidenotes with makeatletter/addtoreset begin with note 0, not 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395108/sidenotes-with-makeatletter-addtoreset-begin-with-note-0-not-1)

This makes the problem go away:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm,paperheight=230mm,bottom=20mm,top=30mm,inner=25mm,outer=35mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[maxfloats=100]{morefloats}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\geometry{
  marginparwidth=2cm,
}

\counterwithin*{sidenote}{subsection}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thesidenote}{\@arabic{\numexpr\value{sidenote}+1\relax}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Hello}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim\sidenote{hello} veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure\sidenote{hello} dolor in reprehenderit\sidenote{hello} in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat\sidenote{hello} cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim\sidenote{hello} veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure\sidenote{hello} dolor in reprehenderit\sidenote{hello} in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat\sidenote{hello} cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim\sidenote{hello} veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure\sidenote{hello} dolor in reprehenderit\sidenote{hello} in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat\sidenote{hello} cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim\sidenote{hello} veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure\sidenote{hello} dolor in reprehenderit\sidenote{hello} in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat\sidenote{hello} cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim\sidenote{hello} veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure\sidenote{hello} dolor in reprehenderit\sidenote{hello} in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat\sidenote{hello} cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim\sidenote{hello} veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure\sidenote{hello} dolor in reprehenderit\sidenote{hello} in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat\sidenote{hello} cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 

\end{document}
```